# ¿Comó puedo asignarle a cada boton de un Carousel slider que navegue a una pagina distinta?

Tags: flutter, dart, app

estoy aprendiendo a programar apps moviles en flutter siguiendo este video tutorial "  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAroZ2-OAaY&t=472s&ab_channel=Dero  " de una aplicación en flutter, y dentro de las modificaciones que le hice al codigo del video logre hacer que los conteiners donde estan los carrusel funcionaran como botones, no obstante, la forma en la que lo hice funciona mal dado que no le puedo asignar una pantalla nueva a cada boton sino que todas rediriguen a una misma pantalla.

Entonces me pregunto si es posible con la forma que tengo escrito el codigo poder asignarle a cada boton una pantalla distinta o es necesario estructurar el codigo de otra forma.

A continuación dejo los estractos de codigo que modifique del video donde agregue los gesture detector

```
import 'package:hielder2/screens/avances.dart';
import 'package:hielder2/screens/mainscreen.dart';
import 'package:hielder2/models/tool.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hielder2/screens/mainscreen.dart';

class CompactItemJob extends StatelessWidget {
  Tool tool;

  CompactItemJob(this.tool);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen())
        );
      },
    child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 7.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: _boxDecoration(),
          height: 125.0,
          width: 100.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _companyLogo(),
                  _infoJobTexts(context),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unos consejos:

Seguramente nadie verá un vídeo de más de 30 minutos. Probablemente, ni de un minuto, por lo que si quieres poner el link al vídeo, Ok, pero es probable que sea innecesario.

Además, te recomendaría poner la parte relativa a la incidencia. En este caso, podrías poner el widget que hace de items para el slider, el cual supongo que es `CompactItemJob` y el propio widget del slider. Los imports no son necesarios realmente. Además, indicar qué es cada cosa, ayudará bastante a entender mejor el problema.

Dicho esto, vamos al lío.

Existen diversas formas de hacer lo que pides, pero al final tú lo que necesitas es tener un argumento variable que indique **cómo** o **a dónde** navegar.

Eso lo puedes lograr pasándolo por parámetro al widget; tal y como haces con el atributo `tool`.

En Flutter existe el `typedef VoidCallback` cuya firma es: `typedef VoidCallback = void Function();`. Puedes utilizar este tipo como atributo dentro de tu widget o crearte uno propio. Te dejo un enlace si quieres aprender más: [ExploreTypeDef](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-typedef-in-dart-fluter-6dd102fdf5f9).

Por tanto tu widget podría quedar cómo:

```dart
class CompactItemJob extends StatelessWidget {
  Tool tool;
  VoidCallback onTap;

  CompactItemJob(this.tool, this.onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      // Pasado como referencia, no necesita paréntesis.
      onTap: onTap, 
      [...]
  }
```

Por último, donde instancias al widgets tendrás que pasarle una función para navegar. A cada widget, tendrás que pasarle una función diferente, así que podrás cambiar la pantalla a la que navega cada widget. Sería algo así:

```dart
CompactItemJob(
      () {
         Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
        );
      },
    )
```

Recuerda marcar mi respuesta como la correcta, si te ha servido y crees que no hay otra mejor; de esa forma, otros usuarios se podrán beneficiar de tu pregunta.